# FLOW error when running "python examples/rllib/traffic_light_grid.py"

Tags: reinforcement-learning, sumo, flow-project

I am trying to run a multiagent experiment on the RL-Framework Flow for SUMO. 
However, if I try to run
`python examples/rllib/traffic_light_grid.py` I get the following errors:

`traci.exceptions.TraCIException: Invalid departLane definition for vehicle 'idm_0'; must be one of ("random", "free", "allowed", "best", "first", or an int>=0)`

and

`traci.exceptions.TraCIException: Vehicle 'idm_0' is not known`

I use the newest flow-version from github and **sumo-version**: Eclipse SUMO Version v1_1_0+0000-2147d155b1

To you know how to resolve this? I already tried running different sumo & flow version.
Thanks and BR

Answer (score 1):

In the SumoParams try setting 'restart_instance=true'